# Do require.resolve for ES modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I need to resolve ES modules, imported via [static import or function-like dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), in a way similar to how CJS modules in `node.js` can be resolved using [require.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options).  Does anything like that exist for ES modules?

For example, if a Vue package have both `vue.runtime.common.js` and `vue.runtime.esm.js`. I need to get path to `vue.runtime.esm.js`. If package doesn't have one, I'd like to know it.

Comment: E.g. Vue package have both vue.runtime.common.js and vue.runtime.esm.js. I need path vue.runtime.esm.js one. If package doesn't have one, I'd like to know it.

Comment: Since ESM is agnostic as to package managers (e.g., the browser doesn't understand `import 'someNpmPackage'`), I don't think you will find an ES way. However, if you know what the path to the vue package will be relative to your module, you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta

Answer (score 70):

As long as `import.meta.resolve` stays experimental, you can use [`createRequire`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename) to get back the `require.resolve` functionality in ES modules, e.g.

```js
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const pathName = require.resolve('vue.runtime.esm.js');
```

Comment: this requires a `tsconfig.json` with `{ "compilerOptions": { "module": "es2020" } }` ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440505/ts1343-the-import-meta-meta-property-is-only-allowed-when-the-module-opti))

Comment: @MilaNautikus This answer is actually for JavaScript, not TypeScript.

Comment: A potential issue is that it picks `package.json#exports["."].require` instead of `package.json#exports["."].import` which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 17):

you can use `import.meta.resolve()`

here is an example from the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_resolve)

```js
(async () => {
  const dependencyAsset = await import.meta.resolve('component-lib/asset.js');
})();
```

note that you need to pass in `--experimental-import-meta-resolve` for this to work, as of node `14.3.0`

Comment: this requires a `tsconfig.json` with `{ "compilerOptions": { "module": "es2020" } }` ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440505/ts1343-the-import-meta-meta-property-is-only-allowed-when-the-module-opti))

Comment: The flag `--experimental-import-meta-resolve` is still required today (`v19.6.1`).

Comment: It's now, since `20.6.0`, available without any flags: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.6.0#:~:text=import.meta.resolve%20unflagged

Comment: But the argument `parent` (aka `cwd`) still requires a flag: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#importmetaresolvespecifier:~:text=When%20using%20the%20%2D%2Dexperimental%2Dimport%2Dmeta%2Dresolve%20flag%2C%20that%20function%20accepts%20a%20second%20argument%3A