# TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'esnext', or 'system'

Tags: node.js, vite

When `Jest.js` encounters `import.meta` in the code, I get an error:

```
FAIL  testFile.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    testFile.ts:40:10 - error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'esnext', or 'system'.

    40          return import.meta?.env as EnvironmentalVariablesType
```

I have installed the following babel related packages:

```
// package.json
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.5",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "1.3.6",
        "babel-jest": "^27.4.5",
        "jest": "27.3.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-global": "3.0.0",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "ts-jest": "27.0.7",
        "typescript": "4.1.3",
        "vite": "2.6.14"
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env": "^1.0.3",
        "babel-preset-vite": "^1.0.4",
```

I've setup `babel.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [ 'babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env' ],
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            { targets: { node: 'current' } },
        ],
        [ '@babel/preset-typescript' ],
        [ 'babel-preset-vite' ],
    ],
}
```

and my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig( {
    base: '/time/',
    server: {
        port: 9000,
    },
    plugins: [
        reactRefresh(),
        replace( {
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'development' ),
            'process.env.SHOW_DEV_TOOLS': JSON.stringify( 'true' ),
        } ),
    ],
} )
```

**Tried**

- set `module` in tsconfig.json to `es2020`, `esnext`, or `system`

None of these cleared or changed the terminal error.

Is there some misconfiguration above that is preventing Jest from properly running babel?

Comment: I am sure you must have tried `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest` as suggested in the Jest website, but did it work? I cannot make it work. I have a React + Typescript + Parcel setup and Jest is giving me big headaches with this problem. Also, for the fun of it, I tried to transpile the project with `tsc` (module esXXXX), change the suffixes to .mjs and try to run the tests again... nothing... rabbit hole getting deeper and deeper.

Comment: For me going to this post and using nstanard's solution solves the issue better than any of the finnicky non-solutions I've found elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72128718/test-suite-failed-to-run-import-meta-env-vite

Comment: Simply changing the import.meta.env.* to process.env.* worked for me.

Answer (score 46):

In `tsconfig.json`, try setting the `compilerOptions` as so:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me and was a quick and simple solution. Thanks for this, been some rough times on a Vue project that uses TS. All these tooling advancements are supposed to make our lives as devs easier, right?! 

Comment: This did not resolve it for me. I get the exact same error after making this change.

Comment: For those who can't fix by these options, try `rm tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` and run again. It seems like the options can be cached and works for me after removing it.

Comment: @foray1010 - where is that file located? it's nowhere in my project

Comment: @Nico if you don't see it, you don't have it. That file is built by `tsc` in the output directory (when appropriate). [See TS Docs for more info.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html)

Comment: Then I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` in \dist\main.js:1 on line `import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'`

Comment: If using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), deleting the auto-generated folder `/.next` might help. This folder will be re-created with the next build. It caches things as well _(FYI see `/.next/cache`)_.

Answer (score 17):

1. Install [vite-plugin-environment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-environment) plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-environment)
2. Create `.env` file in your project root folder near package.json
3. provide your env variables in `.env` files
4. change all your `import.meta.env.YOUR_VAR` to `process.env.YOUR_VAR`
5. open `vite.config.ts` and list the vite-plugin-environment:

```
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment';

...

plugins: [
  react(), 
  ...
  EnvironmentPlugin('all')
]
```

Jest will understand `process.env.YOUR_VAR`, so if you change all your `import.meta.env.YOUR_VAR` to `process.env.YOUR_VAR`  your test will pass without `import.meta.env` error

> [This article helped me for setting up Jest in my Vite project](https://codingwithmanny.medium.com/quick-jest-setup-with-vitejs-react-typescript-82f325e4323f).

Comment: This does not answer what is the problem and why this is a solution you can recomment. Apart from that, to me this also sounds like terrible advice, installing unneeded depedencies just to solve some problem you dont want to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

I switched from `jest` to `vitest`, which got rid of this error.
No changes to the test code were necessary.

For reference, this is my `vitest.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'jsdom'
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sad this got downvoted. Sometimes switching to a more integrated tool is the answer, this helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to TS1343 Error with Jest and import.meta Usage**

I encountered the `TS1343` error while working with Jest in a project using `import.meta` for environment variables. After exploring various configurations without success, I found a simple and effective solution that doesn't rely on extensive Babel configurations.

#### The Approach:

The core of the problem was the use of `import.meta` which Jest struggles with. I circumvented this by abstracting the environment variable access into a separate configuration module.

1. **Create a Configuration Module:**

   ```js
   // src/config/config.ts
   export const config = {
     apiUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
   };
   ```
2. **Use the Configuration Module:**

   Replace direct `import.meta.env` access with the configuration module's properties:

   ```js
   import { config } from "../config/config";
   const { apiUrl } = config;
   ```
3. **Mock the Configuration for Jest Tests:**

   In your test setup or directly within test files, mock the configuration module:

   ```js
   jest.mock("../config/config", () => ({
     config: {
       apiUrl: "http://localhost:mock",
     },
   }));
   ```

#### Adjustments in Jest Configuration:

No Babel configuration was necessary. Here's my `jest.config.js`:

```js
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```

#### Why This Works:

This approach allows Jest to bypass the issue with `import.meta` by abstracting environment variable access through a standard JS module. Since Jest can easily handle module mocks, it provides a smooth testing experience without the hassle of dealing with `import.meta` directly.

I hope this solution helps others facing the same `TS1343` error with Jest and `import.meta`. It's been a straightforward fix for my project, and it may simplify your testing setup as well.

---

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Special thanks for mentioning "Why This Works".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to run the test as per the [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) along with setting allowSyntheticDefaultImports to "true" in ts config file, these two changes solved the error for me.

```
 yarn NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest
```

or

```
npm NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest
```

Ensure you have the relevant modules installed as per this. [This article](https://datacadamia.com/web/javascript/test/jest_ts_configuration), have proper ts, jest and babel config added. (I have shared my config files for anyone who comes across this error. [This article](https://datacadamia.com/web/javascript/test/jest_ts_configuration) came in pretty handy to know about initial set-up requirements.)

```js
//tsconfig.json

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
      
        "target": "ES2020", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: '' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "ES2020", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
        "allowJs": true, /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
 
        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "Node", /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "baseUrl": "src", /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */

        "types": [
          "jest"
        ], /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
        "esModuleInterop": true, /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.js"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
    }
```

```js
//babel.config.js
export default api => {
    const isTest = api.env('test');
    // You can use isTest to determine what presets and plugins to use.

    return {
        presets: [
            [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-typescript',
                {
                    'targets': {
                        'node': 'current',
                    },
                },

            ]
        ],
    };

};
```

```js
    //jest.config.js 
    /** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */

    export default {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testEnvironment: 'node',
      testTimeout: 20000, //to resolve timeout error
      roots: ['src'], 
      modulePaths: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
      testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/', "/__utils"
      ],
      moduleDirectories: [
       "src"
      ],
      transform: {
        "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
      },
      transformIgnorePatterns: [""], // you can add any module that you do not want to transform, The first pattern will match (and therefore not transform) files inside /node_modules. 
      testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js?|tsx?)$",
      "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
      },
      testEnvironment: "node",
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
      },
      globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
          "useESM": true
        }
      },
      extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
      moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is import from `.env` variable global. I have same problem and I resolve from:

```js
export const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE;
const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

To:

```js
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5170' // your api backend
const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```