The import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'
I implemented a hook useEnv that manages environment variables in client components and I'm trying to add unit test with Jest, but I'm facing this issue :
> rehook@1.0.0-beta test
> jest src/hooks/__tests__/use-env.spec.ts

 FAIL  src/hooks/__tests__/use-env.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/hooks/use-env.ts:10:51 - error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.

    10     const envVars = Object.keys(isFrameworkVite ? import.meta.env : process.env)
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.193 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/hooks\/__tests__\/use-env.spec.ts/i.
(node:81266) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

useEnv:
import { NEXT_DEFAULT_ENV_VARS, VITE_DEFAULT_ENV_VARS } from '../constants/env'
import { rehookConfig } from '../rehook.config'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const { ignoreDefaultEnv, framework } = rehookConfig

const isFrameworkVite = framework === 'VITE' // Otherwise it is NEXTJS

export const useEnv = () => {
    const envVars = Object.keys(isFrameworkVite ? import.meta.env : process.env)

    const [variables, setVariables] = useState<string[]>(envVars)

    const ignoreDefaultVariables = () => {
        let ignoredVariables

        if (ignoreDefaultEnv) {
            ignoredVariables = variables.filter(variable =>
                isFrameworkVite ? !VITE_DEFAULT_ENV_VARS.includes(variable) : !NEXT_DEFAULT_ENV_VARS.includes(variable),
            )

            setVariables(ignoredVariables)
        }
    }

    const renameVariable = (oldVar: string, newVar: string) => {
        const index = variables.indexOf(oldVar)
        if (index !== -1) {
            const updatedEnv = [...variables]
            updatedEnv[index] = newVar
            setVariables(updatedEnv)
        }
    }

    const updateVariable = (currentVarVar: string, newValue: string) => {
        if (variables.includes(currentVarVar)) {
            setVariables(prevEnv => ({
                ...prevEnv,
                [currentVarVar]: newValue,
            }))
        }
    }

    const removeVariable = (currentVar: string) => {
        if (variables.includes(currentVar)) {
            const filteredVars = variables.filter(value => value !== currentVar)
            setVariables(filteredVars)
        }
    }

    const saveVariable = (variable: string, value: string) => {
        localStorage.setItem(variable, value)
    }

    const deleteVariable = (variable: string) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem(variable)) {
            localStorage.removeItem(variable)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        ignoreDefaultVariables()
    }, [])

    return { variables, renameVariable, updateVariable, saveVariable, removeVariable, deleteVariable }
}


env.spec.ts:
import { useEnv } from '../use-env'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('use-env', () => {
    it('should  return at least one variable', () => {
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useEnv())
        expect(result.current.variables.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
    })
})


tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "module": "ESNext",
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        /* Bundler mode */
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",

        /* Linting */
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}


jest.config.ts:
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const config: Config = {
    verbose: true,
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
}

export default config


vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});


CodeSandbox

Why not use Vitest? Then you don't have to have two sets of config.

I have already made 12 tests with Jest. I expect it will take time if I switch to Vitest and refactor the tests for the time being.

12 is a pretty small number. Also Vitest is API-compatible with Jest: https://vitest.dev/guide/migration.html#migrating-from-jest

Thank you @jonrsharpe, it took only 10 mins to migrate from Jest to Vitest. and the issue is solved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440505/ts1343-the-import-meta-meta-property-is-only-allowed-when-the-module-opti/78141628#78141628
