# How do I use “require” and ESM “import” in the same project?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, es6-modules

I use node version 16.14.2, and I try to use ES Module in my project. Below my ***package.json***.

```
{
  "name": "community",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "community",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "sequelize": "^6.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.4.1"
  }
}
```

I use Sequelize for ORM, and I use sequelize-cli to generate model.
My model ***models/userModel.js***

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  User.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

and this is my ***controllers/userController.js***

```
import User from '../models/userModel.js'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import generateToken from '../utils/generateToken.js'

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  const { first_name, last_name, email, password } = req.body
  const userExists = await User.findOne({
    where: { email: email },
    order: [ [ 'createdAt', 'DESC' ]],
  });
  res.send('ok', userExists);
})
```

I have tried this :

a).I use import on my controller

```
import User from '../models/userModel.js'
```

But then I get an error

> SyntaxError: The requested module '../models/userModel.js' does not
> provide an export named 'default'

b). So I change my Model to be like this one (use import and export default)

```
'use strict';
import { Model } from 'sequelize'
const userModel = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  User.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
export default userModel;
```

I don't get any error on server, but when I try to fecth data (register user), I get error on my postman.

> "message": "User.findOne is not a function",
> "stack": "TypeError: User.findOne is not a function\n ....

Thank you.

Comment: see also [module.createRequire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977743/do-require-resolve-for-es-modules)

Answer (score 7):

```
import Module from "node:module";

const require = Module.createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Here is the `require` you’re looking for. Use it to import what the ESM `import` doesn’t support, such as Node.js add-ons (`.node`).

Answer (score 2):

> How to use require and esm in 1 project?

Don't. It creates a mess. Use modern module syntax when not working in a legacy project.

> I use Sequelize for ORM, and I use sequelize-cli to generate model.

The `sequelize-auto` command supports [a `-l esm` parameter](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto#es6) to generate ES6 ESM modules.

Comment: well - but what if the dependent package has no esm bundle? Luckily this answer works perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755289/6090293

Comment: @PetrPlenkov You can still [`import` from commonjs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs) just fine, especially if it's a separate package. But in *your* project, you should always use ES module syntax.

Answer (score -1):

**`import-js`** is a command-line tool that helps in converting CommonJS **`require`** statements to ECMAScript Modules (ESM) **`import`** statements.

Here we can use require and import feature in same file.

1. first add this line in package.json file,
   "type": "commonjs"
2. then add these line of code in server.js/index.js file

```
import Module from "node:module";
const require = Module.createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

3. then change the extension of server.js file server.mjs. and don’t forget to change server.js extension in package.json file as well :-
   "main": "server.mjs",

here we go,

Comment: well. isn't it the same as Konstantin suggested eariler? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755289/6090293